C# WebForms ReportViewer Cannot Change Port From 443 to 80
I am trying to run an SSRS report programmatically in C# from an existing internal server that does not have HTTPS enabled.
The code is as follows:
string reportName = ("/report/AFolder/AReport");
// Variables
Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamIds;
string mimeType;
string encoding;
string extension;

string[] paramNames = new string[0];
string[][] paramDic = new string[0][];

ReportViewer rv = new ReportViewer { ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote };
ServerReport sr = rv.ServerReport;
sr.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://pfs-reports:80/reports");
sr.ReportPath = reportName;

if (paramNames.Length != 0)
{
    List<ReportParameter> paramList = paramNames.Select((t, i) => new ReportParameter(t, paramDic[i])).ToList();
    rv.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList);
}

return rv.ServerReport.Render("Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

But I keep getting this error, that indicates that it is trying to connect over port 443.

System.Net.WebException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=Unable to
connect to the remote server   Source=System    SocketException: No
connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
it 192.168.9.101:443

Anyone know how I can change the port to use port 80?

I was able to resolve my problem. The Report Server Web Service URLs that was provided to me was incorrect. i was able to find the correct one in the Reporting Services Configuration Manager, and once I used that the process worked.
